Programmatically interact with git-lfs
I am using the GitHub API to create git commits via REST API calls. In Go it looks like this:
newBlob, _, err := a.github.Git.CreateBlob(ctx, orgName, repoName, &github.Blob{
    Content:  github.String(base64EncodedFileContents),
    Encoding: github.String("base64"),
})

newTree, _, err := a.github.Git.CreateTree(ctx, orgName, repoName, mainBranchSHA, []*github.TreeEntry{{
    Mode: github.String("100644"),
    Path: github.String("path/in/repository"),
    SHA:  newBlob.SHA,
}})

This works great, but my repository uses git-lfs for some files, and I'm wondering if there is a way to programatically interact with git-lfs. I already know which files should be stored on git-lfs and which should not be. Can I push some data to git-lfs and then store the appropriate pointer to that data in a git blob? What is the format and API for that, and is there a git-lfs library in Go?
I know that git-lfs itself is implemented in Go and I've looked through the repository, but I didn't find an example of interacting programmatically with git-lfs. In fact the README in the repository explicitly warns that:

we do not maintain a stable Go language API or ABI, as Git LFS is
intended to be used solely as a compiled binary utility. Please do not
import the git-lfs module into other Go code and do not rely on it as
a source code dependency.


Yes this is possible. I had to write my own git-lfs client in Go. I will release it as a github project and post a link.
